# AMPD algorithm QRS peak detection off slightly

Tags: algorithm, rust

I have implemented the [AMPD peak detection algorithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiOn9Cem5PLAhXDQCYKHUWsDC0QFggxMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F1999-4893%2F5%2F4%2F588%2Fpdf&usg=AFQjCNEeU4Ylz-RzzIkJh12ekr36I-3EDA) in Rust. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/adaptium/peak/blob/develop/src/ampd.rs). From the figure you can see that the peak detection is close but not exact:

```
Black = peak detected, Orange/Red = ECG
```

[image: Black = peak detected, Orange/Red = ECG]

This seems to be causing problems when I find the HRV of ECG data from [physionet.org](http://physionet.org). With [HRV toolkit](https://physionet.org/tutorials/hrv-toolkit/) the rMSSD and SDNN are:

```
$ get_hrv -M chfdb/chf03 ecg 0:00:00 0:01:00
chfdb/chf03 :
...
SDNN     = 31.727
...
rMSSD    = 53.1993
...
```

Using the same 1 minute range of data I find the peaks using my implementation of AMPD, the RR-intervals from these peaks, and then the rMSSD and SDNN:

```
SDNN = 122.23032809963584 msec 
rMSSD = 173.6491690112714 msec
```

I have confirmed that my SDNN, and rMSSD calculations are correct by using the RR-interval data from HRV Toolkit and substituting these into my rMSSD and SDNN implementation:

```
$ rrlist ecg chfdb/chf03 -s -f 00:00:00 -t 00:01:00
Seconds RR
1.356 0.952 N
2.312 0.956 N
3.252 0.940 N
4.212 0.960 N
5.156 0.944 N
6.112 0.956 N
7.048 0.936 N
7.996 0.948 N
8.960 0.964 N
9.900 0.940 N
10.872 0.972 N
11.820 0.948 N
12.772 0.952 N
13.716 0.944 N
14.656 0.940 N
15.604 0.948 N
16.544 0.940 N
17.492 0.948 N
18.436 0.944 N
19.388 0.952 N
20.332 0.944 N
21.276 0.944 N
22.056 0.780 N
23.164 1.108 N
24.096 0.932 N
25.028 0.932 N
25.960 0.932 N
26.900 0.940 N
27.836 0.936 N
28.768 0.932 N
29.696 0.928 N
30.616 0.920 N
31.544 0.928 N
32.484 0.940 N
33.408 0.924 N
34.348 0.940 N
35.276 0.928 N
36.208 0.932 N
37.136 0.928 N
38.060 0.924 N
38.988 0.928 N
39.924 0.936 N
40.852 0.928 N
41.784 0.932 N
42.712 0.928 N
43.648 0.936 N
44.572 0.924 N
45.500 0.928 N
46.420 0.920 N
47.352 0.932 N
48.296 0.944 N
49.220 0.924 N
50.156 0.936 N
51.088 0.932 N
52.012 0.924 N
52.940 0.928 N
53.864 0.924 N
54.796 0.932 N
55.728 0.932 N
56.652 0.924 N
57.580 0.928 N
58.504 0.924 N
59.436 0.932 N
```

I get close enough to the same values from HRV Toolkit:

```
rMSSD = 52.77095975580117 msec
SDNN = 31.528528844213298 msec
```

I have also ruled out that my RR-Interval calculation is wrong. The output is comparable to the output from the above `rrlist`:

```
Seconds RR
1.36    0.952
2.312   0.944
3.256   0.96
4.216   0.944
5.16    0.952
6.112   0.94
7.052   0.948
8   0.96
8.96    0.944
9.904   0.964
10.868  0.952
11.82   0.952
12.772  0.944
13.716  0.94
14.656  0.948
15.604  0.944
16.548  0.944
17.492  0.948
18.44   0.948
19.388  0.952
20.34   0.94
21.28   1.88
23.16   0.936
24.096  0.936
25.032  0.932
25.964  0.936
26.9    0.936
27.836  0.932
28.768  0.928
29.696  0.916
30.612  0.932
31.544  0.94
32.484  0.928
33.412  0.936
34.348  0.928
35.276  0.932
36.208  0.924
37.132  0.924
38.056  0.936
38.992  0.928
39.92   0.932
40.852  0.936
41.788  0.928
42.716  0.932
43.648  0.928
44.576  0.924
45.5    0.924
46.424  0.932
47.356  0.94
48.296  0.924
49.22   0.932
50.152  0.936
51.088  0.924
52.012  0.932
52.944  0.924
53.868  0.928
54.796  0.936
55.732  0.924
56.656  0.928
57.584  0.924
```

So I am left to think that the peak detection is the source of the faulty HRV numbers. How can I improve upon the current implementation to get a more reliable peak detection?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem, and *include* that code here in your post. Please note the **Minimal** part of MCVE; don't just paste in your entire program. Ideally, reduce it to something that can run on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/).

Comment: @Shepmaster Can I use external crates on Rust Playground?

Comment: Sadly, you cannot use external crates. It's certainly not *required* to run on the Playground; it's just very convenient if you can. If the crates are your own, then maybe try copy-pasting the important parts. It's also possible that when you minimize the code, those crates won't be needed anymore. To restate - it's absolutely OK to use external crates if they are crucial to reproducing your problem.

Comment: Have you tried running it on a tiny example set of data? e.g. `detect(&vec![0, 1, 0])`. (BTW, `&Vec<T>` is pointless: use `&[T]` if you only need a borrow, or `Vec<T>` if you need ownership. `&Vec` can be borrowed to `&[]` and in fact does it implicitly, so the latter is strictly more flexible than the latter.)